# PhpStorm complains "Path not found" using "require_once" with dirname $levels parameter

Tags: phpstorm

This is the line of code:

```
require_once dirname( __DIR__, 2 ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

The code works, but PhpStorm complains with:

> Path 'C:/project/src/Container/vendor/autoload.php' not found

The correct path is:

> C:/project/src/vendor/autoload.php

If I use a relative path, PhpStorm doesn't complain:

```
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php'; // no complaints
```

So it looks like PhpStorm is not recognizing the 2nd parameter of [dirname($path, $levels)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php), where I'm specifying to go up 2 levels.

`dirname()` is such a basic PHP function that I'm really surprised that PhpStorm doesn't recognize the `$levels` parameter.

I would prefer to keep inspections on. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: The levels parameter was added in PHP 7. Are you sure your web server's PHP engine is at version 7?

Comment: In Settings->Languages&Frameworks->PHP I have "PHP language level" set to 7.2

Comment: what you end up doing, living with it.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dirname()` levels aren't supported yet in PhpStorm, here's a link to a corresponding feature request that you can vote for: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35143. This would increase the issue priority & would move it up in a queue